# javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit / RTF is an 8-bit format

Tags: java, swing, htmleditorkit

I need a simple converter for HTML2RTF and
i try to run follow code.... but i got a error for this code example

**Code:**

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFEditorKit;

public class converter {
    private static Pattern htmlTrimPattern = Pattern.compile(".*<body>(.*)</body>.*", Pattern.DOTALL);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        toRtf("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                "</html>\n");

    }

    public static String toRtf(String html) {
        ByteArrayInputStream input= new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            RTFEditorKit rtfEditorKit = new RTFEditorKit();
            HTMLEditorKit htmlEditorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
            Document htmlDoc = htmlEditorKit.createDefaultDocument();
            htmlEditorKit.read(input, htmlDoc, 0);
            rtfEditorKit.write(writer, htmlDoc, 0, htmlDoc.getLength());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error"+ex);
        }
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Errorjava.io.IOException: RTF is an 8-bit format
```

what am I doing wrong? google is in this case not my friend and i hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 7):

[RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) is an 8-bit format, but you're sending content to a `Writer`, which is a "class for writing to character streams." Try the variation of `write()` that takes a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
…
rtfEditorKit.write(baos, htmlDoc, 0, htmlDoc.getLength());
…
System.out.println(baos.toString());
```

Console:

```
{\rtf1\ansi
{\fonttbl\f0\fnil Monospaced;}

\par
My First HeadingMy first paragraph.\par
}
```